# Why shell and browser return diffrent ip address?

Tags: network-manager, proxy, wget, ip

I set global WebProxy by UBUNTU setting->network->networkProxy and then i open

> http://whatismyipaddress.com/

and i get my proxy ip address but when i use this command:

> wget -qO- http://ipecho.net/plain

I get my real ip address,Does not shell use global proxy setting ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use wget with a proxy, use the *--proxy=on* option and export the proxy address with *export http_proxy="http://proxy.example.com:8080"*

See here: http://tech.gaeatimes.com/index.php/archive/how-to-use-wget-through-proxy/ or check the wget man page https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html